# AVAudioRecorder writes malformed file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

This code worked, but when I moved to iOS 6 it stopped supporting mp4.

I prepare write

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Temp.mp4"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 32000], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                nil];
NSError *error = nil;
self.audioRecorder = nil;
AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorderBuffer = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                                        initWithURL:soundFileURL
                                        settings:recordSettings
                                        error:&error];
self.audioRecorder = audioRecorderBuffer;
self.audioRecorder.delegate = self;
if (error)
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
else
    [self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

then record, sto, save it and when I try to play:

```
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_audioURL error:&error];
_audioPlayer.delegate = self;
if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
else {
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    if (![_audioPlayer play]) {
        NSLog(@"Play Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

I get and error:

Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

The code works on uncompressed format.
Compressed mp4 works on iPhone 4 with iOS 6, worked also on iphone 4S with iOS 5.x, but does not work on iphone 4S nor iphone 5 with iOS 6.

AVAudioRecorder records and writes the file, then AVAudioPlayer has error Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.).
Documentation states that file format is corrupted.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It finish the recording, but files are not playable. Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following before `[self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord]`

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Check out this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435683)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a very similar issue with corrupted files - for me it came down to the fact that those who couldn't record had denied permission to access the microphone. This meant that `prepareToRecord` was working (and truncating the file) and `record` was reporting that it was working, but actually it wasn't recording anything.

This code (swift not Objective-C) gets the permission state:

```
let val : AVAudioSessionRecordPermission = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission()
switch( val ){
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.Undetermined :
    print("permission undetermined")
    break
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.Denied :
    print("permission denied")
    break
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.Granted :
    print("permission granted")
    break
default :
    print("permission unknown")
    break
}
```

And I used this in when I want to record:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
    if granted {
        self.internalRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        self.internalRecorder.record()
    } else {
        // can't record - update UI
    }
})
```

Hope it saves someone some time if they run into the same issue.