# Record audio and convert it to .wav

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I need to make an app that sends recorded audio in .wav format to a REST endpoint. I will be using `AFNetworking` for the POST, but I am not sure where to go with recording the audio and then converting it. I know I should use `AVFoundation` to record, but I am not sure how to convert. Would `CoreAudio` help?

Comment: Why Converting ? Record in ".wav" format

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435683/ios-audio-recording-file-format